# AWS Cognito role: Distinguish between Federated Identity Pool roles and User Pool Group roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, permissions, amazon-cognito, roles

I have an application wherein I want 2 types of users to belong to the same User Pool. They all authenticate using the same AWS Cognito Federated Identity Pool. The first type of user, Manager, should be able to see all of the other users in their group and change their attributes. The second type, Employee, should only be able to see/change their own attributes, change their own password, forget their own password, etc. I imagine this specific case requires some policy "magic" to create 2 roles, each with different levels of permissions. I figure that each role would be assigned to a different group, with the Manager group getting more power/permissions. But I am confused by the redundancy of role assignments in both Federated Identity Pools and User Pool Groups.

- AWS Cognito Federated Identity Pools have 3 role specifiers: "Unauthenticated role", "Authenticated role", and for Authentication Providers, "Authenticated role (selection)."
- AWS Cognito User Pool Groups allow you to specify an IAM role.

What is the relationship between Identity Pools and Groups in terms of permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using groups and attaching roles to them you can then choose to use the role that is provided in the token. By default the authenticated role (or unauthenticated role if you have it activated) is used whenever you log in. You can change this behavior by opening your federated identity pool and changing this setting under cognito user pool (which i assume is your identity provider).
[image]

Select "choose role from token" to use the role that you have attached to the group that the user belongs to.

Comment: But I'm still confused by this - IF i assign the role to the cognito user pool group - why do I even need an identity pool at all? The redundancy in cognito really confuses me, it seems like it could be simplified a lot

Comment: @DanielCooke the mistake you are making is assuming that user pool and identity pool are tied. Think of them as individual services that work very well with each other but can work independently of each other just fine. Then the redundancy starts making sense.

Comment: That is a great way of thinking about it! - thank you. I wish my AWS course explained it like that - but they are always seemly referenced together.