# AWS Amplify - Cognito User Group members lose permissions granted by the default authRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have created a couple of Cognito User Groups named "admins" and "editors" which has in turn created IAM roles as expected `{USERPOOLID}-adminsGroupRole`. These IAM roles have no policies attached and when a user becomes a member of this group it appears that any permissions they were granted via the default authRole as a non-group user are completely ignored.

I would expected the authRole to be applied to anyone who is authenticated and my admins/editors group to provide additional permissions. If this is the way it works I am then expected to generate custom policies in my CloudFormation templates which already exist elsewhere, and they'd need to be dynamic to work for multiple environments/buckets etc. which is a ballache.

Am I approaching this wrong or misunderstanding? This behavior seems very odd.

Thanks

Comment: Technically user can only assume one role at a time. It's up to you which one (group
 or Identity Pool). You can find more about how Cognito decides which role to use here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html

Answer (score 0):

When using Amazon Cognito User Pools (and not Identity Pools), when you create a group and specify an IAM Role, [their permissions are determined by the group's associated IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html#assigning-iam-roles-to-groups).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you say: `I would expected the authRole to be applied to anyone who is authenticated and my admins/editors group to provide additional permissions.`

This `authRole` is the IAM Role defined in the Identity Pool for all users that have been authorized. You can control which role is being selected in the settings of your Identity Pool.

More information in this answer:
[AWS Cognito role: Distinguish between Federated Identity Pool roles and User Pool Group roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332522/aws-cognito-role-distinguish-between-federated-identity-pool-roles-and-user-poo)

Comment: Correct - the authRole should be associated with anyone who is authorized. My additional user pool groups i've created 'admins' and 'editors' I would expect to inherit this role by default, but they don't. So any permissions I need that are granted to the authRole, I need to then re-apply on the custom groups. Bearing in mind I need to do this all through cloudformation, I find myself writing a lot of duplicate code in the user-pool-group-precedence.json file to get users who are admins or editors to have the same permissions as those who have no group.